# Join two tables with mysql and order by date

Tags: mysql, union

I have looked at many supposed solutions to this problem, but I still cannot get this to work.

```
SELECT Year FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(detDate1) AS Year 
FROM growl_details WHERE publish = 'y' AND pubNews = 'y' 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(detDate1) AS Year FROM growl_pl_details
WHERE publish = 'y' AND pubNews = 'y') AS t ORDER BY 'Year' ASC
```

I have two tables, growl_details and growl_pl_details, I am trying to get them to display just the years which information exists, this will then be used to create a table with links to data pages concerned with that year.

Obviously I want the years to show in order, but the above code seems to order them individually and they follow on from each other..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your query (formatted so I can read it):

```
SELECT Year
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(detDate1) AS Year
      FROM growl_details
      WHERE publish = 'y' AND pubNews = 'y'
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(detDate1) AS Year
      FROM growl_pl_details
      WHERE publish = 'y' AND pubNews = 'y'
     ) AS t
ORDER BY 'Year' ASC;
```

The problem is due to the `order by` clause.  Try changing the single quotes to back quotes:

```
ORDER BY `Year` ASC;
```

Single quotes are used for string constants.  Back quotes surround names of things.  So, your original query was ordering by a constant -- which produces an arbitrary ordering.

Comment: Gordon, Many thanks for the help. It was frustrating me and I was overlooking the obvious. I need to take a break every now and then, focus the mind.